# Replicate border focus behavior lightning input

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, css, lightninginput, lightning-inputfield

I'm using this repository because I needed a multi select combobox like this and works fine except the input is not a lightning-input so it doesn't have the blue border focus like this:
[image]

https://github.com/svierk/awesome-lwc-collection/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/multiSelectCombobox

Right now the input border focus is black like standard, I tried to override with this css class, but it just become a very tiny blue border and doesn't have the shadow:
[image]

```
.multi-select-combobox__input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: rgb(21, 137, 238);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #0070d2;
}
```

Comment: I've found the real reason - check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time trying to figure this out. It's actually mostly because of this rule:

```
.multi-select-combobox__dropdown {
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Change this to `overflow-y: visible;`

I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, but I think it's related to the amount of space surrounding each element.

Also, you'll want to set `slds-has-focus` on your input to prevent it losing focus:

```
<input class="slds-combobox__input 
              multi-select-combobox__input 
              multi-select-combobox__dropdown 
              slds-has-focus" >
```

You might want to do with this with a click handler on select or input.

You'll still want this rule, I think:

```
.slds-combobox__input:focus, .slds-combobox__input.slds-has-focus {
  border-color: var(--slds-g-color-brand-base-60, var(--lwc-colorBorderInputActive,rgb(27, 150, 255)));
  box-shadow: var(--lwc-shadowButtonFocus,0 0 3px #0176d3);
}
```

I found a writeup about this [here](https://medium.com/@timothyde/using-overflow-y-while-retaining-shadows-de5938f8fe1b). They solved by adding negative margins and padding, but I found just changing `auto` to `scroll` worked.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, the border became black :\

Comment: That solve :) The behavior was having focus even when was not clicked, and when was clicked the border becam black, so I changed a fell things, I remove the slds-has-focus and in the css I add the outline: 0; So now it has the same behavior that the a lightning input

Comment: Thank u!!! :)))

Comment: It was quite a puzzle to solve, but I really wanted to figure it out! I have my own components that also suffer from this, but I hadn't bothered to worry about them before.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm very detal-oriented, so it was something that was bothered me. I can share my code if you would like, hope you find a solution too :)

Comment: Oh, it solved it for me too! I'm going to add it to my components in the near future :)

Comment: Happy to know hah :) thanks again

Comment: Hi, I'm struggling with this now :\ if you could take a look.. thanks!
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/405102/pre-select-values-in-multi-select-combobox